# Can we find or construct a decreasing subsequence in $(x_{n})_{n≥1}$ converging to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(x_{n})_{n≥1}$ be a real sequence converging to $0$.

My question: Can we find or construct a decreasing or increasing subsequence in $(x_{n})_{n≥1}$ converging to $0$.

Comment: No. Consider $x_n=-\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: If the question is either decreasing or increasing then yes, since any sequence of real numbers have a monotone subsequence. (and any subsequence of $(x_n)$ obviously converges to $0$).

Comment: @Thorgott How about $x_n$ itself? It is an increasing subsequence of $x_n$, even if you don't like the idea of letting it be itself, then you could take away finitely many terms, or rather, leave infinitely many terms and it would still be an increasing subsequence

Comment: @BrunoAndrades, Thorgott had posted their comment before OP updated their question.

Comment: If this sequence consists of infinitely many non-negative values, you can construct decreasing subsequence. Similarly if it consists of infinitely many non-positive values, then you can construct increasing subsequence. Any sequence will satisfy at least one of the above conditions.

Comment: @rtybase Oh, I see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, we will construct a decreasing or increasing sequence out of any sequence.

We call $x_n$ a point of no return if for every $m\geq n$, $x_n\geq x_m$, if $\{x_n\}$ has infinitely many points of no return, then we just construct the subsequence made just by the points of no return and we will have an
 decreasing subsequence.

If $\{x_n\}$ has only finitely many points of no return, then, let $x_r$ be the last point of no return, then $x_{r+1}\geq x_r$, but since it isn't a point of no return, there must be an $r_0$ such that $x_{r_0}\geq x_{r+1}$, but since $x_{r_0}$ isn't a point of no return there must be an $r_1$ such that $x_{r_1}\geq x_{r_0}$ and so on. This way we constructed an increasing subsequence.

This plus the fact that every subsequence of a convergent sequence converges to the same value, gives us what we wanted.